# Vue 3 second condition runs twice on click

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, conditional-statements, vuejs3

I'm calling two Conditions in an OnClick function. but the second condition renders twice:

```
<div class="col-md-6" v-if="scan.played"
   @click="scanAction(scan.id, 'stop'); scan.played = !scan.played">
 <i class="btn fas fa-stop"></i>
 </div>
```

the second condition which is `scan.played = !scan.played` runs twice, so the `v-if` wont also happen
it changes the `played` to `true` and again turn it back to `false` ASAP

---

```
data() {
return {
  scanList: {},
  played: false
}
},
```

and the method:

```
async scanAction(id, string) {
  await this.$store.dispatch('axiosPost',
    {url: `/scans/${id}/${string}`, formData: {
      }
    }).then(response => {
  if (response.data.status === 200) {
    this.getData()
  }
  if (response.data.status === 'error') {
    return this.$swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'مشکل در داده های ورودی',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    })
  }
})
},
```

Comment: so `scanAction` also runs twice? try `@click.self=" ........ "`

Comment: Is there any change that `scanActions` toggles the `played` flag? Can you provide more details / code?

Comment: yes both run twice

Comment: I'll add the other functions too.

Comment: you could also move the `@click` to the `<i` instead of the `<div`

Comment: `it's like, it changes the played to true and again turn it back to false` - actually, if `scan.played` is false, the div wouldn't even show ... so, it's changing it from `true`->`false`->`true` - but I believe wither one of my 2 suggestions will fix it

Comment: I checked it again, and only the boolean condition runs twice. I'vr tried the stop and prevent solution but doesn't work

Comment: impossible that only the `scan.played = !scan.played` runs twice, since it runs AFTER the function call, the fucntion call must have happened - `tried the stop and prevent solution` but I said `.self`, not `.stop` or `.prevent`

Comment: Why do you have a direct `played` variable on your data but use `scan.played` on template ? where is the `scan` obj ? onclick should run things once, no matter how many statements you put in there, so the problem is not vue. please provide more code